# Who wrote "The Monsters" short story published by Purnell?

Tags: short-stories, authors

I have a sci-fi book from the 80's: *Purnell's Book of Adventures in Space* (ISBN 0361044070).

Many of the stories have kept in my mind for so many years, particularly "The Monsters":

> From his bedroom window, Zek watched the great space battle in the skies.

The twist is that

> the Monsters are Human Beings

Does anyone know the author's name?

Comment: That's not much of a [twist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumansAreTheRealMonsters), now is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My research [suggests](http://www.durdlesbooks.com/?page=shop/flypage&product_id=1617) that the authors of the various stories are Fred Baker, Malcolm Hulke, John Grant, David Meredith, William Hall, Sydney Bounds, George Beal and Jim Storrie.

I've seen multiple [sources](https://www.librarything.com/topic/74962) indicating that the author of the story "The Monsters" was Malcolm Hulke, of Doctor Who fame.

[image: Credit from the front of the book]

Comment: The [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?578513+c) concurs. Seems like a weird question, though. The OP has a copy of the book? The authors are not credited in the book?

Comment: @user14111 - I seem to recall talking about this when the question first came up. If memory serves, the book doesn't credit individual authors for individual works. I believe the OP also didn't still have access to the book.

Comment: The credits at the beginning of the book indeed credit Malcom Hulke for that story.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Can you post a scan or a photo?

Comment: @valorum Image added

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Needs more hand-drawn red circles but other than that, cheers for assisting ;-)